# How to migrate files to SharePoint using CSOM while retaining publishing history

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

We are planning to migrate documents from an existing Document Management System into SharePoint Server 2019. The chosen API is CSOM, since there is a chance that the target SharePoint solution will move from on-premise to online.

The requirements is to retain the document history, which means that created, modified, author and editor fields should be controlled during migration. Also the time of publishing and publishing comments should be provided during migration.

I am aware that the item.UpdateOverwriteVersion() will do most of the job, but I can't seem to figure out how to publish the document by setting the fields _UIVersionString and _CheckinComment. If I use the file.Publish("comment") function I loose the editor and modified field values.

So how do I both control editor, modified values when document needs to be published in major versions?

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Lars Kohsel

Answer (score 0):

For update file you can try this construction down below:

```
FileInformation fileInformation = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, relativeSrcUrl);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    CopyStream(fileInformation.Stream, memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, relativeDestinationUrl, memoryStream, true);
}
```

For check in major or minor you can try use this:

```
yourFileObject.File.CheckIn("Add", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
```

Not forget ExecuteQuery().

Comment: When using .CheckIn() with majorVersion the custom set editor and modified values are overwritten.  The intension is to create a document version history of published versions that resembles that of the document before migrating to SharePoint. If I omit using checkout/checkIn I am able to set the editor and modified values, but then the document will not be in a major version as intended. How do I obtain both controlling the editor and modified value and checkin as majorversion?